# Regular expression is too complex error in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I have not seen this error for a small list. Issue popped up when the list went >10k. Is there any limit on the number of regex patterns in tcl?

```
puts "#LEVELSHIFTER_TEMPLATES_LIMITSFILE:$perc_limit(levelshifter_templates)"
puts "#length of templates is :[llength $perc_limit(levelshifter_templates)]"
if { [regexp [join $perc_limit(levelshifter_templates) |] $temp] }

#LEVELSHIFTER_TEMPLATES_LIMITSFILE:HDPELT06_LVLDBUF_CAQDP_1 HDPELT06_LVLDBUF_CAQDPNRBY2_1 HDPELT06_LVLDBUF_CAQDP_1....
#length of templates is :13520
ERROR: couldn't compile regular expression pattern: regular expression is too complex
```

Comment: I tried out with a smaller list and dont see the error if the list was upto 1950 elements. I think there is a ceiling to use this command.

Comment: Something is making the RE engine complain about the depth of stack it would need to build that. Which… is something I've _never_ seen before in production! But then I've never seen a RE that must be on the order of 100kB in size. Yowch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$temp` is a single word and you're really just doing a literal test, you should invert the check. One of the easiest ways might be:

```
if {$temp in $perc_limit(levelshifter_templates)} {
    # ...
}
```

But if you're doing that a lot (well, more than a small number of times, 3 or 4 say) then building a dictionary for this might be best:

```
# A one-off cost
foreach key $perc_limit(levelshifter_templates) {
    # Value is arbitrary
    dict set perc_limit_keys $key 1
}

# This is now very cheap
if {[dict exists $perc_limit_keys $temp]} {
    # ...
}
```

If you've got multiple words in `$temp`, split and check (using the second technique, which is now definitely worthwhile). This is where having a helper procedure can be a good plan.

```
proc anyWordIn {inputString keyDictionary} {
    foreach word [split $inputString] {
        if {[dict exists $keyDictionary $word]} {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

if {[anyWordIn $temp $perc_limit_keys]} {
    # ...
}
```

Comment: This is good solution, but does not work for patterns with * and other regexes. If I have a list of 10,000+ regex patterns which I want to match with a cellname $temp, its giving the error that the regex is too complex.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to see if the value in `temp` is an exact match for one of the elements of the list in `perf_limit(levelshifter_templates)`, here's a few ways that are better than trying to use regular expressions:

Using [`lsearch`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsearch.htm)`:

```
# Sort the list after populating it so we can do an efficient binary search
set perf_limit(levelshifter_templates) [lsort $perf_limit(levelshifter_templates)]

# ...

# See if the value in temp exists in the list
if {[lsearch -sorted $perf_limit(levelshifter_templates) $temp] >= 0} {
    # ...
}
```

Storing the elements of the list in a dict (or array if you prefer) ahead of time for an `O(1)` lookup:

```
foreach item $perf_limit(levelshifter_templates) {
    dict set lookup $item 1
}

# ...

if {[dict exists $lookup $temp]} {
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple workaround for this problem by using a foreach statement to loop over all the regexes in the list instead of joining them and searching, which failed for a super-long list.

```
foreach pattern $perc_limit(levelshifter_templates) {
    if { [regexp $pattern $temp]} 
        #puts "$fullpath: [is_std_cell_dev $dev]"
        puts "##matches: $pattern return 0"
        return 0
    }
}
```